# Multiple inheritance for interfaces

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

Is there a way to define an interface who inherits from two or more interfaces?

I tried the following code on Delphi2007:

```
  IInterfaceA = interface
     procedure A;
  end;

  IInterfaceB = interface
    procedure B;
  end;

  IInterfaceAB = interface(IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB);
```

.. and it raised an E2029 error:

> E2029 ')' expected but ',' found

at line:

`IInterfaceAB = interface(IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB)`.

Comment: Last paragraph explains why it was never done for the windows compiler: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29779

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no multiple interface inheritance in Delphi as there is no multiple inheritance in Delphi at all. All you can do is make a class implement more than one interface at once.

```
TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB)
```

Answer (score 7):

In Delphi interfaces cannot inherit multiple interfaces, but classes can implement multiple interfaces. If you design your components properly (look up ISP - interface segregation principle) you should not need to have interfaces inheriting from interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, in this case, you must define three types. 
One per interface and third for multiple inheritance :

```
  IInterfaceA = interface
     procedure A;
  end;

  IInterfaceB = interface
    procedure B;
  end;

  TiA = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterfaceA)
    procedure A;
  end;

  TiB = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterfaceB)
    procedure B;
  end;

  TMyObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB)
  private
    _iA : IInterfaceA;
    _iB : IInterfaceB;
    function getiA : IInterfaceA;
    function getiB : IInterfaceB;
  public
    property iA : IInterfaceA read getiA implements IInterfaceA;
    property iB : IInterfaceB read getiB implements IInterfaceB;
  end;
{.....}
{ TMyObject }

function TMyObject.getiA: IInterfaceA;
begin
  if not Assigned(_iA) then _iA := TIA.Create;
  Result := _iA;
end;

function TMyObject.getiB: IInterfaceB;
begin
  if not Assigned(_iB) then _iB := TIB.Create;
  Result := _iB;
end;
```

Comment: Although this is a possible approach, it is not really necessary. You can as well implement procedures A and B in TMyObject directly.

Comment: yes, of course but with this approach, it's easiest to modify implementation  of each interface. 
without having to modify the implementation of the layers using. This avoids edge effects on more complex projects